# How to remove my question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I have a question about my Server Fault post: [Vxlan Outer MAC Header](https://serverfault.com/questions/879037/vxlan-outer-mac-header)

Can I delete my question if I later understand that's a wrong question? If not can someone do that for me for the linked one? Or should I self-response explaining why I think it's an inopportune question?

Answer (score 3):

As long as no answer has been posted to your question, you should be able to just delete it, without any comment or explanation. Once an answer has been posted, you can no longer delete it. Moderators (♦) could, but we do that only if nothing of value would be lost by this deletion (e.g., both question and answer are bad and/or wrong).

Comment: The help page [.../help/deleted-questions](https://serverfault.com/help/deleted-questions) indicates that also when there is already a single answer, the OP  can also still delete the question as long as that answer has garnered no up votes. - No idea what happens for the edge-case where if the OP self-answered and that is the only answer, but it does have up votes...

Comment: @HBruijn: Ah, yes, you are right. The edge case likely could be resolved by just deleting your own answer and then the question, as you can delete your own answers even if they have upvotes.

Comment: I would just add that if the question was downvoted, even erased it still count toward the ban on asking question